# searchkick autocomplete and suggestions not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have this in my controller

```
@events = Newevent.search params[:search], suggest: true, partial: true, misspellings: {distance: 4}
```

and this in my model

searchkick suggest: [:eventname]

Now the autocomplete i have typeahead.js which looks like this

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ (would add but too large)

I havent put anything in my model as of yet for the autocomplete however the suggestions i have this in my view

```
<%= @events.try(:suggestions) %>
```

This returns nothing.

Ideas?

Sam

Comment: did you reindex your database after adding searchkick suggest to your model

Comment: believe i did, However i'll attempt again @sachin

Comment: So a no results found keeps coming up but thats it :)

Comment: I am in a same scenario not able to add autocomplete so create a manual one with help of jquery and ajax

Comment: @sachin  Any chance you could share?

Comment: I can give you code for jquery but you need to rectify a lot.

Comment: You just need to use jquery autocomplete library Then rectify this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".autocomplete-cls").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(".autocomplete-cls").val();
    $("#query1").val($("#query_label1").val());
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/properties/autocomplete",
        data: { query: value },
        success: function(msg){//console.log(msg);
            var availableTags = msg;

            $( ".autocomplete-cls" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,                        
                select: function( event, ui )  {
                    $("#query1").val(ui.item.value);                         
                    $('#property_type, #price, #bed, #bath, #floor').val('');
                    setTimeout(function(){$("#query_label1").val(ui.item.label);$(".search_form1").submit();}, 100);                           
                },
                focus: function( event, ui )  {
                    $("#query_label1").val(ui.item.label);                      
                }

            });   
          }
    });
});
```

Create a action for response with name auto-search

```
event = NewEvent.search(params['keyword']).map(&:name)
render :json => event
```